# Unstructured to Structured Data

Tags: database-design, database-agnostic

This is highly a research based question about converting the unstructured textual data to structured data. Are there any systems or tools perform automated process of converting the unstructured data  **without human interventions** to structured data sets? The unstructured data flows from different resources can be directed to a tool/software to be extracted automatically.

Comment: There are lot of tools for parsing data.  But you typically would need to customize for the specific data.  This might be a better fit on another SE site.  You even have machine learning for classification and clustering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the data. Stanford's [NER](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) (GPL license) can pull out date/time, names of individuals and companies, locations, monetary amounts, in popular human languages.

A lot of data and work went into building the models, and if you need to build a custom model then you'll need a lot of data and work.